# How to delete a file from S3 using full path to the file instead of key for the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to delete a file from AWS s3. I don't have a key for that file. Instead, I have a full path URL to that file.
like: https://atlms.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/folder/606ae1d032b0e7asdfkjh.image

Can I delete the file like this:

```
const fileParams: S3.Types.PutObjectRequest = {
Bucket: bucketPath,
Key: key //here I have only the URL to the file 
}
s3.deleteObject(fileParams, function (error) {
console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the S3 key from the URL. In this case, the S3 key is `folder/606ae1d032b0e7asdfkjh.image`.